# HttpWebRequest system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to develop a C# to upload videos. I'm using `httpwebrequest` and the application works there are few threads to upload the videos but when I try to increase the threads some of the videos fail to upload and the thread gets this exception:

> An operation on a socket could not be performed because the system lacked sufficient buffer space or because a queue was full

I don't know what the exact problem is but maybe it has to do with limited memory when the application tries to buffer multiple videos before uploading.

I simply want to upload multiple videos simultaneously... Any solutions?

Comment: Are you properly disposing the httpwebrequests by wrapping them in a `using` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to set the `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property to `false` on the HttpWebRequest.

Also, did you consider using System.Net.Http's HttpClient api which has a better programming model?

Comment: How is the `AllowWriteStreamBuffering` property related to a WSAENOBUFS error?

Comment: the default value of this property is true, so if we are uploading huge files at the client, you could see the files being buffered first before they being written over the wire...sorry but i am not clear on what you meant by 'WSAENOBUFS error'